# Run Program from byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have a program stored in byte array.

Is it possible to run it inside C#?

Comment: Lets say I have simple program that shows text "Hello" stored inside byte array

Comment: What is the content of that array? Sourcecode, executable code?

Answer (score 16):

Yes.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959087/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-x86-assembly-sequence-from-within-c/959144#959144) shows you can directly execute the contents of a byte array.  Basically, you use [`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887%28VS.85%29.aspx) to allocate an executable region on the heap with a known address (a [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28VS.71%29.aspx)).  You then copy your byte array to that address with [`Marshal.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146635.aspx).  You convert the pointer to a delegate with [`GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx), and finally call it as a normal delegate.

Answer (score 12):

Sure.

1. Save the byte array to an `.exe` file.
2. Use the `Process` class to execute the file.

**Note**: this is assuming that your byte array is executable code, and not source code. This also assumes that you have a valid PE header or know how to make one.

Comment: Is it possible to do that but without actually saving byte array into exe file? Also yes it is executable.

Comment: @DanSpd, no. The OS doesn't allow you to execute a separate process from an in-memory executable. You can, with sufficient wizardry, execute in-memory code within your *own* process space, but this is highly not recommended. And it will make your program look like malware to many scanners, since this technique is often used by viruses and other undesirables.

Comment: You may not be able to spawn it in a second process, but you can run it in a new appdomain.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming the byte array contains a .net assembly (.exe or .dll):

```
 Assembly assembly = AppDomain.Load(yourByteArray)
 Type typeToExecute = assembly.GetType("ClassName");
 Object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToExecute);
```

Now, if typeToExecute implements an interface known to your calling program, you can cast it to this interface and invoke methods on it:

```
 ((MyInterface)instance).methodToInvoke();
```

Answer (score 8):

If the byte array is a .Net assembly with an `EntryPoint` (Main method) you could just do this.  Most of the time `returnValue` would be `null`.  And if you wanted to provide command line arguments you could put them in the `commandArgs` string listed below.

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBuffer);
var entryPoint = assembly.EntryPoint;
var commandArgs = new string[0];
var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { commandArgs });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a virtual machine and execute the code OR you could use reflection and dynamic types to create a dynamic assembly, potentially. You can dynamically load assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx

You could thus perhaps do something with that. If my memory serves me though there are some limitations.

See

Reflection
Assembly.Load
Application Domain