# What causes the error "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing"?

Tags: java, aes, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string using AES but getting an error I don't know how to resolve. This is the code:

```
public class EncryptionTest{

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String encrypt = new String(encrypt("1234567890123456"));
    System.out.println("decrypted value:" + (decrypt("ThisIsASecretKey",encrypt)));
}

public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        byte[] raw = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encrypted string:" + (new String(encrypted)));
        return new String(skeySpec.getEncoded());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(key), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(skeySpec.getEncoded(),"AES"));
            (*)
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));
        original.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}  
}
```

When I run it the "decription" values is null. It fails before the (***) !!

It gives me an exception:

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Parameters missing
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:388)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:186)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:787)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:849)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1213)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1153)
    at firma.XmlEncryptionTest.decrypt(EncryptionTest.java:63)
    at firma.XmlEncryptionTest.main(EncryptionTest.java:41)
```

where the line 63 is the one before (***). I don't know what am I doing wrong and how to solve. I looked around on the internet but without finding out what coul be that missing parameter

Comment: you are using two different init() for your cipher... try using same.

Comment: Yes, this part `new SecretKeySpec(skeySpec.getEncoded(),"AES")` looks odd - why not use `skeySpec` directly?

Comment: @DuncanJones , if I put "skeySpec" insted of "new SecretKeySpec(skeySpec.getEncoded(),"AES")", I get a new error: Invalid AES key length: 12 bytes , at the same line...

Comment: @Shark I used the same init() for both the ciphers "cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);" and I got the exception: Invalid AES key length: 12 bytes

Comment: It's not the same... Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198228/not-decrypting-what-i-crypted)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The main issue in your code was caused by a failure to specify an IV value. You must specify an IV value when doing CBC-mode encryption and use that same value when performing the CBC-mode decryption.

Another problem is the mix and match of creating strings from byte arrays and base64-encoding. You also return `null` from your decrypt method every time. Even if you meant `return original.toString();`, that's still wrong (because `toString()` doesn't do what you wish it would on a byte array).

Below is an improved version of your code. It's far from optimal, but it compiles and works. You need to improve this to use a random IV. **Also, if you plan to derive keys from passwords, don't just get the bytes, use a derivation function such as PBKDF2**. You can see an example of using PBKDF2 in the [JNCryptor source](https://github.com/RNCryptor/JNCryptor/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256JNCryptor.java#L152).

```
public class EncryptionTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

      String key = "ThisIsASecretKey";
      byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(key, "1234567890123456");
      System.out.println("decrypted value:" + (decrypt(key, ciphertext)));

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static byte[] encrypt(String key, String value)
      throws GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    if (raw.length != 16) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,
        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    return cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  }

  public static String decrypt(String key, byte[] encrypted)
      throws GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    if (raw.length != 16) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
    }
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,
        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

    return new String(original, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  }
}
```

Comment: If a random or zero IV is created (if at all) depends on the specific JCE provider. The smart thing to do is not to use provider defaults but always provide an IV for those modes that require it. You should always explicitly request the right block cipher mode and padding mode for the same reason.

Comment: You wrote "You must specify an IV value when doing CBC-mode encryption and use that same value when performing the CBC-mode decryption." and then "You need to improve this to use a random IV." QUESTION: If I need the same IV for decryption, how can I use a "random" one?

Comment: @user9999999 The IV is not a sensitive value, so you typically store/send it with the cipher text.

Comment: Hello @simpleuser , since the `IV` needs to match, then one way is for each side to have a list of possible `IV` values, then both side has to agree on an index to decide which `IV` to use. This index has to be communicated during the initial handshake of the communication.

Answer (score 12):

If you use a block-chaining mode like CBC, you need to provide an IvParameterSpec to the Cipher as well.

```
public class EncryptionTest {

static byte[] raw = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};

static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

static IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(16));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String encrypt = encrypt("1234567890123456");
    System.out.println("decrypted value:" + (decrypt("ThisIsASecretKey", encrypt)));
}

public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {

        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        System.out.println("encrypted string:" + Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String key, String encrypted) {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 10):

Even though its too late but still I'm giving my solution for others.Please refer below working code to encrypt and decrypt data.

```
public static byte[] encrypt(String value) {
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {

            byte[] raw = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
            Key skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];

            IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,ivParams);
            encrypted  = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("encrypted string:" + encrypted.length);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public static  byte[]  decrypt(byte[] encrypted) {
         byte[] original = null;
         Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            byte[] raw = new byte[]{'T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'I', 's', 'A', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y'};
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            //the block size (in bytes), or 0 if the underlying algorithm is not a block cipher
            byte[] ivByte = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
            //This class specifies an initialization vector (IV). Examples which use
            //IVs are ciphers in feedback mode, e.g., DES in CBC mode and RSA ciphers with OAEP encoding operation.
            IvParameterSpec ivParamsSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamsSpec);
            original= cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return original;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It works and helped me out :D