# Execute Byte array as a new program

Tags: c#, arrays

I am creating a program to see if I can run a byte array in C#.

The program should grab a byte array "MyBinaryData" and Load+Run it as a new program.
There will be a text box where you can enter the bytes to see the outcome (it's a experiment ;) ).
I have tried this:

```
 byte[] binaryData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("MyBytes.txt");  // the bytes are in a .txt file for simple tests before becoming a textbox.
 Assembly LoadByte = Assembly.Load(binaryData);
        MethodInfo M = LoadByte.EntryPoint;

        if (M != null)
        {                object o = LoadByte.CreateInstance(M.Name);
            M.Invoke(o, new Object[] { null });  // this gives the error
        } 
        else {  
         ..... fail code here.... 
             }
```

The problem is that it gives this error:
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:......SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application."

My second test was:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(binaryData);

 Type bytesExe = assembly.GetType(); // problem: the GetType(); needs to know what class to run.
 Object inst = Activator.CreateInstance(bytesExe);
```

But this needs to know what class in the byte array it needs to run.

I then tried:

```
var bytes = Assembly.Load(binaryData);
var entryPoint = bytes.EntryPoint;
var commandArgs = new string[0];
var returnValue = entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { commandArgs });
```

But it gave me this: 
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application."

My program.cs is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Crypter
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
}
```

}

What other way can I do this to have the Whole program opened?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly you are not just typing random bytes, the byte[] you are using is an assembly, a Winforms one.  Which does *not* like it when you call EnableVisualStyles() after the program already got started.  Well, when the bytes do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two way

first way make .exe from that byte array and then start it

second look at this [execute byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959087/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-x86-assembly-sequence-from-within-c/959144#959144)

Comment: @AZInventor is your byte array C# program or not?

Comment: Read this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18677/Dynamic-Assemblies-using-Reflection-Emit-Part-II-o