# C# load raw bytes

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I've developped a small decrypt and execute application and I'm stuck at the execution part. 
I succesfully execute .NET assemblies using the method below:

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(decryptedBytes);   
 if (asm.EntryPoint == null)
     throw new ApplicationException("No entry point found!");

 MethodInfo ePoint = asm.EntryPoint;
 object ins = asm.CreateInstance(ePoint.Name);
 ePoint.Invoke(ins, null);
```

But when I try allocating an executable region using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959087/is-it-possible-to-execute-an-x86-assembly-sequence-from-within-c/959144#959144) the application crashes

The only useful information I get is this:

```
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_0a9e
```

Here is my code:

```
  const uint PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40;
  const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000;

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

  private delegate int IntReturner();

IntPtr buf = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, (uint)decryptedBytes.Length, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
Marshal.Copy(decryptedBytes, 0, buf, decryptedBytes.Length);

IntReturner ptr = (IntReturner)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf, typeof(IntReturner));
Console.WriteLine(ptr());
```

Comment: what does VirtualAlloc return? It might be NULL

Comment: Are you sure you need Assembly.Load and VirtualAlloc? The question you've linked talks about native code execution...

Comment: I need to execute all .exe application. I'm not into this area at all and I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help: http://www.nokola.com/TryCSharp/HowToBuild.aspx In this project the assembly is compiled on a server, its raw bytes are transferred to a Silverlight client, where it's loaded into an AssemblyPart.