# Dynamically injecting a parameter into a function call in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, parameters

I was wondering if it was possible to dynamically inject a function parameter at runtime. For e.g. I have a class with two overloaded methods say

```
Class C1
{
    public static void Func1(object o)
    {
    }

    public static void Func1()
    {
    }       
}

Class C2
{

    public void Func1()
    {
       C1.Func1();
    }
}
```

Now, is it possible to dynamically replace the call to Func1() with a call to the overloaded method C1.Func1(object o) passing in either 'this' or the type object as the parameter.

So, in affect when I call C1.Func1(), my code should call C1.Func1(this);

Comment: I am guessing he wants to intercept/shunt an already compiled piece of code to which he does not have source code access, but knows publics.

Comment: One way would be to decompile the exe to MSIL, make the changes and recompile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that by "dynamic" you mean a post-compile time solution, but not necessarily at runtime. The latter would be more challenging but could be done. For the former it's rather easy if you know some IL. I note that `C2.Func1` compiles to something like

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Func1() cil managed {
    call void SomeNamespace.C1::Func1() 
    ret 
}
```

which you can easily replace with

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Func1() cil managed {
    ldarg.0
    call void SomeNamespace.C1::Func1(object)
    ret 
}
```

This is because argument zero in an instance method is always the `this` reference for the current instance and we can push it on the stack with the instruction `ldarg.0`. Moreover, we simply replace the signature of the method that we are invoking from the parameterless method to the method accepting a single `object` as a parameter.

You can easily decompile to IL using [`ildasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) and recompile using [`ilasm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Jason, that certainly works, however could you explain a bit more about the other option that you suggested, i.e. at runtime, would that mean using the Profiler API as suggested by Am?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an extension method:

```
public static class C1Extensions
{
    public static void Func1(this C1 o)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class C1
{
    public void Foo()
    {
       this.Func1();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, was just about to post the same thing, however, still requires the "this" keyword to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

1. Decompile the binary to MSIL, do the changes manually and recompile it.
2. User the .NET profiling API to inject code, here is an [article] discussing it.
3. Similar issue [code-injection-with-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241/code-injection-with-c)

The code injection would be to intercept the function without the argument, and recall the function with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

As your method is static there is no way of obtaining the calling object.

Your options are to either make your methods non static and create a C1 object, or, pass the C2 (this) object in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using extension methods to do this?

```
public static class C1WrappingExtensions {
    public static void Func1(this object instance) {
        C1.Func(instance);
    }
}

// Now you can just call Func1() on any object...
var me = new Whatever();
me.Func1();
```